# Firebase Cloud Messaging does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to show a notification on my application. I created an application on Firebase console. Note: There is no error. When the application start after I send a message from Firebase console nothing appears. What's wrong here?

`MyFireBaseInstaceIDService.java`

```
package com.example.hp.mesajlasma;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
// [START refresh_token]
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
// [END refresh_token]

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
}
}
```

`MyFireBaseMessagingService.java`

```
package com.example.hp.mesajlasma;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

/*** Created by Belal on 5/27/2016.*/

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha5'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`AndroidManifest`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hp.mesajlasma">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
       Defining Services
   -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

`build.gradle` (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.mesajlasma"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',              {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: look at this link and accept the answer if it gets it to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997957/fcm-not-receiving-notifications-when-the-app-is-relaunched/37998202#37998202

Comment: i added the permission but it still does not work. it makes me crazy...

Comment: Did you add the `google-services.json` file to your project?

Comment: what are you using as the target from the console? Have you tried sending to the Instance ID token generated by the firebase-messaging? Also I'd suggest using v 9.4.0

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution...

Answer (score 2):

All files looks fine except MyFireBaseMessaginService.java
Compare it with mine and do changes and it should work.

```
package biz.coolpage.rjabhi.tesstingfcm;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

/**
 * Created by Warrior on 8/8/2016.
 */
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

    private void showNotification(String message) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("FCM TITLE").setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you have registered your app at [FCM console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and generated googleservices.json after entering your app's package name.

MainActivity.java

```
package biz.coolpage.rjabhi.tesstingfcm;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("TOKEN",FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
    }
}
```

FireBaseInstanceIDService.java

```
package biz.coolpage.rjabhi.tesstingfcm;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

/**
 * Created by Warrior on 8/8/2016.
 */
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("GOT TOKEN: ",token);
        registerToken(token);
    }

    private void registerToken(String token) {
//code to save token
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work. My MainActivity.java is empty. there is no any code. is there any code in MainActivity.java file ?

Comment: check your logcat. are you getting Token there?
Seems like it's just sample project of GooGleQuickStart? If that's the case make sure you register project on FCM Console and get your own googleservices.json and paste it in app directory of project

Comment: 08-09 17:13:20.877 3163-4348/com.example.hp.mesajlasma D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE, retry in 160s

Comment: WHEN I SENT A MESSAGE IT GIVES THIS.

Comment: 08-09 17:10:50.807 3163-3189/com.example.hp.mesajlasma W/InstanceID/Rpc: Failed to resolve REGISTER intent, falling back
08-09 17:10:50.811 3163-3189/com.example.hp.mesajlasma W/InstanceID/Rpc: Both Google Play Services and legacy GSF package are missing
08-09 17:10:50.811 3163-3179/com.example.hp.mesajlasma I/FA: This instance being marked as an uploader

Comment: Are you using Emulator or An android phone etc to run The app?

"08-09 17:10:50.807 3163-3189/com.example.hp.mesajlasma W/InstanceID/Rpc: Failed to resolve REGISTER intent, falling back 08-09 17:10:50.811 3163-3189/com.example.hp.mesajlasm..."
And that is your log cat?

Comment: If it's Emulator then it will have no googleplayservices installed, so connect your Android phone with Android-Studio and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

Make simple process for Firebase notification.

Download sample code from below link :

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android 
(it's 100% working)

For test about notification:

Go to firebase console - > select your application

Choose Notifications section  -> Click on New message and add your message and click on Send Message.

Answer (score 0):

For setting up FCM, as described in [Set up Firebase and the FCM SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client), the first step states to [add Firebase to your Android project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

You may need to add`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'` (*appropiate version i.e. 9.0 if you prefer older version, so that there is no inconsistency, I included the latest version as of now*) if you have followed along all other steps to add Firebase to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Just import firebase messaging into your project.
You need to add this line in app module gradle file.

```
//Add this line firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    /
```